# How to integrate checked out local git project with Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, git, maven

I checked out a maven project (foo) from GitLab to my local windows box (H:/my_git_project/foo) where git bash is available.

I created a local branch "foo_local" out of "develop" branch via "git checkout -b foo_local" command.

I opened up eclipse IDE (e.g. luna) then created new Java Project (File > New > Java Project). The workspace is set to "H:/my_git_project/foo" directory.

My question is how can I differentiate whether this eclipse project is pointing to "develop" branch or "foo_local" branch?

Comment: You should really consider moving to Eclipse Neon. Many things were improved since Luna.

Answer (score 1):

You should not set the workspace location to your Git project folder. It's usually a bad practice as Eclipse IDE is meant to support multiple projects from different sources simultaneously in the same workspace.

Instead, consider setting the workspace to a totally different folder (it's only use to store your preferences and settings, not necessary to store the code you're working on), and use `File > Import > Git > Projects from Git repository` and let the wizard guide you. In the end, you should see you `foo` folder imported as project, connected to Git, with annotations on the tree to see which branch you're working on, and ability to control it via the `Repositories` view.

In case Eclipse IDE doesn't automatically detect a project is connected to Git, you can try `right-click on project > Team > Share` to enable Eclipse Git features.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see the folder (the directory which as your .git) name followed by the branch name next to the project name.

For eg, in the below picture you can see that the Project name is "Linux Kernel" but also next to it is the folder name followed by the branch that is currently checked out (which is master branch).

[image]

In your case, since you created and also checked out to "foo_local" branch, you should be able to see this branch next to the project name in Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't see "foo_local" branch name next to the project name. I assume that it is pointing to "develop" branch then...

Comment: It should display the branch that you have currently checked out. Which branch is it showing then ?

Comment: Project name shows as "foo".

Comment: I suspect that the git plugin on your eclipse is not installed or not working properly. Also, you are importing the project in a wrong way. The right way of importing an existing maven project is File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects -> Browse for the pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

I believe there must be right way to do it however In the end, this is what I came up with to meet my goal.

1. cloned "foo" repo from remote repository via git clone command in git bash environment.
2. checked out local branch "foo_local" from "develop" branch.
3. pushed "foo_local" branch to remote repo without changing any files.
4. deleted entire "foo" folder from local box.
5. activated eclipse IDE.
6. installed git plugin (egit).
7. clone "foo" repo vis the plugin: File > Import > Git > Clone URL.
8. selected "foo_local" branch in the process of cloning.
9. import as Java project (tried Maven first but it was asking for group id artifcatc id and etc so I abandoned the process).
10. project name is "foo foo_local"